# Create contact list that is synchronized with permissions group

Tags: list, groups, contacts

Is it possible to create a contact list that is synchronized with a specific permissions group? The goal of this is to have a shared contacts list so that everyone within a permissions group has everyone else's contact information and can then sync the list with their outlook if they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box this is not possible to create such a list. The use case of a contact list is more to store additional accounts related to a site or project.
For the contact internal contact information you can use a exchange distribution group.

The site user web part is capable to show user from a specific SharePoint group on the web page.

You can also email enable [SharePoint user groups](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/send-e-mail-to-members-of-a-sharepoint-group-HA010086731.aspx)